# Azure Bot Services - How to add Long description Setting of Bot which is used by skype channel

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

As per this migration policy [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-migrate-bot], we have migrated our bot to azure bot services, but we are not able to find option to edit the Long Description of the bot, which is used by Skype bot to show description of the bot in bot directory.

Can someone point to where that option is available in Azure bot services?

Image of Bot Description setting on dev.botframework.com

[image]

Comment: What is the ID or name of your bot?

Comment: I have migrated my test bot first to check the new azure bot service. Cant share the id publicly.

Comment: I am going to report this as a bug. In the meantime, I am going to look for a work around. If you can't wait, there is always the option to roll back, change the description and migrate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you can edit the bot's description under Channels -> Publish section:

[image]

Regards,
Francisco